# confidence interval using binofit() --- MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, mathematical-optimization

does someone got an idea on an easy way to carry:

```
n=.....; %integer defined
[freq,cifreq]=binofit(x,n,0.01);
cifreq*n
```

The matter is that

```
cifreq
```

is not a perceived as a variable by Matlab and stored in memory although it values (1* 2 vector)  are displayed on the output screen. Hence the difficulty to automate some calculations such as:

```
cifreq *n
```

within scripts

Thanks

Comment: Where is the problem? Could you explain what exactly is not working with the code from above?

Comment: initially i've used  `cifreq*n` within the command window which trigerred `Undefined function or variable 'cifreq`. However keeping the same syntax  within the m.file produced the desired output in the wake of a latest trial a few seconds ago.

Comment: The m.-file is a function or a script?

Comment: actually a function.

Comment: If you want to access the variable from the workspace (or a script), you need to define it as [global](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html).